# Sort list based on character matching in Lisp

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

Calculates and returns a list of candidate based on their common characters in spelling.

For Example,
If list was : (TEAM TEEN THAN THEM THEN TIME TOWN)
And you provide argument in function ("thim")
then it should sort list by their similarity of common characaters in list.
It should return: (THEM TIME TEAM THEN THAN TOWN TEEN)
Since THEM has more common character with "thim" so it goes first and so forth.

My attempt:

```
       (defun correctSX_SIM(word)

        (setf w (correctSX word))  ; w is list of words.
        (sort w #'eq :key #'car)

       )
```

I know my answer is way off. But I need help with LISP since i dont know all in built functionality of LISP.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, define a special variable for your list of known words:

```
(defparameter *dictionary* '(TEAM TEEN THAN THEM THEN TIME TOWN))
```

You have to define a *distance* function for words which meets your requirements. If I am not mistaken, the following should work:

```
(defun distance (u v)
  (- (length (intersection (coerce u 'list)
                           (coerce v 'list)))))
```

We look at the number of elements in common in both strings and negate it, so that elements which share a maximum number of elements have the lowest scores. I don't know if it matters but long identical strings have a lower score than short identical ones.

Based on your requirements, you need to perform a stable sort, so that words that are at the same distance from the chosen word keep their relative ordering. That's also why I use the strict `#'<` comparison function: when comparing two words *a* and *b* having an equal distance to the input, the comparison returns `nil` for both *a < b* and *b < a*, allowing [`STABLE-SORT`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_sort_.htm) to know that *a* and *b* are equivalent w.r.t. the partial order.
Note also that I use [`COPY-LIST`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_cp_lis.htm) to avoid mutating the dictionary. The actual sort is done as follows for your example:

```
(stable-sort (copy-list *dictionary*) 
             #'< 
             :key (lambda (e) (distance "THIM" (string e))))

=> (them time team than then teen town)
```

The result is slightly different from your example, but I think it is conform to [your comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35424772/sort-list-based-on-character-matching-in-lisp/35428139?noredirect=1#comment58585709_35428139): *THAN* should come before *THEN* because (i) in this case the distance is identical and (ii) they appear in that order in the original list.

As noted in comments by @jkiiski, the distance function might be called once for each comparison (i.e. *O(n.log(n))*). It seems to me that in that particular case the distance function is quite cheap but with large data-sets and more complex distances, it might certainly pay off to cache intermediate results. You have at least two options:

- Define another distance function which caches already known results ([memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)). The advantage of this approach is that you keep a strict separation between the sorting part and the distance function. This should be sufficient:

  ```
  (ql:quickload :memoize)
  (org.tfeb.hax.memoize:memoize-function 'distance
                                         :key #'identity
                                         :test #'equal)
  ```
- Precompute distances into another list containing `(distance string)` couples, and sort according to the first element. Then, extract all second elements to have a sequence of strings. Apparently this is known as a [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform) (thanks Svante). Here the whole process is a little more explicit:

  ```
  (defun sorted-dictionary (input-word)
    (let ((list
            (stable-sort
              (loop for word in *dictionary*
                    collect (cons 
                              (distance input-word (string word))
                              word))
               #'<
               :key #'car)))
      (map-into list #'cdr list)))
  ```

There is a major difference, though: with the *memoized* version, you keep known results across different invocations of the sort (unless you explicitely clear them), whereas with *sorted-dictionary*, you discards intermediate distances once the resulting list is computed.

Comment: You shouldn't use `levenshtein:distance` as :KEY, because the key function gets called every time `sort` makes a comparison (I guess it's implementation dependent, but on SBCL in this case it's called 19 times). Probably better to map the list into conses that have the distance, and then use `#'car` as :KEY.

Comment: @jkiiski Looks as if CLHS doesn't prescribe how the key function is called, so either "once and remember" or "every time" are perfectly valid. However, doing a mapping pass, returning `(cons (key element) element)`, then sort, using `:key #'car` and finish off with `(mapcar #'cdr ...)` is guaranteed to only call the (expensive) key once per element.

Comment: That pattern (decorate, sort, undecorate) has a name, by the way: Schwartzian transform.

Comment: Coredump, Can you tell me what should i pass as distance in sored-dictionary function? Thank you

Comment: The distance argument should be a function of two string arguments. I am not sure exactly how to compute it because I don't really understand what is your criterion for sorting words. If you could detail a little bit the comparison algorithm, that would help.

Comment: It should sort it based on which element in list has most common characters with string that gets passed in function.
for Example,  if argument you are passing is "CAT" and list is ("CAM", "COT", "TAC") it should sort the list like ("TAC", "CAM", "COT")
TAC goes first since C, A and T all three characters are common in T,A and C. Second one would be CAM since two character matches and COT has two character matches. So they shouldnt changes their placaes.

Comment: @Sagar0921 I think I have a correct distance function, see edits

Answer (score 1):

There is a [Levenshtein distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Levenshtein_distance) algorithm for measuring the difference between two words. [Here](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Algorithm_Implementation/Strings/Levenshtein_distance) you can find complete implementation for Common Lisp. Also, the easier way to show a difference between two strings is `set-difference` function as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9257110/4101334).